# (Used to work!) Get Facebook Picture and Copy To Server

Tags: php

I have this code in `PHP` that used to work but now it isn't working.

I'm trying to grab the user's profile picture from Facebook, then copy and paste it into a directory on my server.

```
 $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_userID.'/picture?type=large';
 $data = file_get_contents($url);
 $fileName = 'users/avatars/'.$fb_username.$fb_userID.'.jpg';
 $file = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
 fputs($file, $data);
 fclose($file);
```

**Update:** This code will put a `jpg` image into my directory with a size of `0 Kb` so I'm pretty sure the content is never being grabbed correctly. Please help!

Comment: This is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to adjust something in my `php.ini` file (or `php5.ini`) on my server.

I had to change this:

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

To on:

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

Done.